# How to Showing a Keyword Search in Page Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to showing keywoard search in Search Page. I dont know why my code it didnt showing. While i call may code, its showing a keyword title my website.

And showing total the search result

I'm using a Codeigniter Framework.

This my Controller

```
public function search(){
            $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
            $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
            $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

            $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword');
            $data['search_data']=$this->Product_model->get_product_keyword($keyword);
            $this->load->view('frontend/search_view',$data);
        }
```

This My Search_View

```
<?php
  header('Cache-Control: no cache');
  session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');; 
  echo form_open('search', array('method'=>'get')); ?>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Cari">
  <?php echo form_close() ?>

  <table>
  <h2>Search Result <?php echo $keyword['keyword']; ?>, **(9999)** Results
     <br>
  </h2 >
      <?php foreach($search_data as $men); { ?>
        <tr>
          <?php echo form_open('dashboard/beli');?>
          <td><?php echo ($men->name); ?></td>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>


  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declare the `keyword` variable on your controller :

```
<?php

    public function search(){
        $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

        $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword');
        $data['search_data']=$this->Product_model->get_product_keyword($keyword);
        $data['keyword'] = $keyword; // added keyword data
        $this->load->view('frontend/search_view',$data);
    }

?>
```

And in you *Search_View* you just call the `$keyword` without the `['keyword']` index key :

```
<h2>Search Result <?php echo $keyword; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks youu ma broooo!!, its very detail for me :D

Answer (score 0):

You must to assign the variable $keyword to the array $data in the controller like this:

```
$data['keyword'] = $keyword;
```

and show it in the view like this:

```
echo $data['keyword']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in view code:

```
<h2>Search Result <?php echo $search_data['keyword']; ?>, **(9999)** Results
```

In keyword place,which variable you accessing from table should be place.

Comment: thanks for info, but this code undefined indeks broo :(